# How many ways are there to create a controller and what are they?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, overrides, url, controllers

I have been developing with Magento 1.9 for the last two weeks. I have found several problems to develop each project (probably because my first project with magento had a high level...).

I come from developing mainly with Yii Framework and sometimes I do not find the way to develop some things which were very easy using Yii.

Using Yii, I could create a controller, add a function actionPage and I could access the controller/page url. However, using Magento, I only have seen that everything is done through a module.

Then I would like to know some real life example about "when I should create a controller with a module". On the other side, I would like to know if there is another way to develop a controller. This is only a theorical question.

Thanks.